# Strange behaviour when piping to `signif()`

Tags: r, dplyr, operator-precedence

I've been playing around with some astronomical data and come across some odd behaviour when I try to pipe certain values to `signif`.

For example, in the context of approximating the circumference of the Earth, `signif(6400 * 2 * pi, 2)` yields `40000` (the correct answer), while `6400 * 2 * pi %>% signif(2)` yields `39680`:

```
library(dplyr)

rad_earth_km <- 6400
n_digits <- 2

# Option 1 (gives the correct answer)
circ_earth_1 <- signif(rad_earth_km * 2 * pi, n_digits) # Yields 40000

# Option 2 (gives the wrong answer)
circ_earth_2 <- rad_earth_km * 2 * pi %>% signif(2) # Yields 39680
```

Passing over whether piping is actually appropriate here, I'd like to understand why these two methods are giving different results in these and similar cases. I use piping quite a lot in my more technical work so this is a bit worrying to me.

Answer (score 3):

I worked out the answer pretty quickly after posting the question. It's a [BIDMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics) issue:

```
library(dplyr)

rad_earth_km <- 6400
n_digits <- 2

# Option 1 (gives the correct answer)
circ_earth_1 <- signif(rad_earth_km * 2 * pi, n_digits) # Yields 40000

# Option 2 (gives the wrong answer)
circ_earth_2 <- rad_earth_km * 2 * pi %>% signif(2) # Yields 39680

# Option 3 (given the correct answer again)
circ_earth_3 <- (rad_earth_km * 2 * pi) %>% signif(2) # Yields 40000
```

It hadn't really occurred to me before that `%>%` would interact with `*` in this way. Possibly worth keeping this up in case someone else runs into similar issues.

Comment: Makes sense. Extra () when in doubt... This also gives the wrong answer ` pi %>% signif(2) * 2 * rad_earth_km`

Comment: For some reason I'd find it much more intuitive that the mathematical operators would group together when evaluating the expression. Never mind.

Comment: Playing around, it looks like all the mathematical operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `^`) evaluate after `%>%`.